# please help me to understand this code of python recursion?

Tags: python, function, class, recursion

```
def is_even(x):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)


print(is_odd(17))
print(is_even(23))
```

Comment: Please format this code. I suggest using triple ` instead of spaces to denote the code block.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Try `is_even(0)`, that's obviously `True`, right? then try `is_even(1)`, it calls `is_odd(1-1)`, which is `is_odd(0)`, which returns `not is_even(0)`, so `False`. Then try `is_even(2)`, which returns `is_odd(2-1)` which is `is_odd(1)` which returns `not is_even(1)`, which returns `is_odd(1-1)`, which is `is_odd(0)`, and we already know the answer for that... Now try `is_even(3)` on your own :D

Comment: This seems like a strange use of recursion.

Comment: @DialFrost sorry, in my original comment, i forgot to copy the `not`. `is_even(2)` returns `is_odd(2-1)` which is `is_odd(1)` which returns `not is_even(1)`, which is `not is_odd(1-1)`, which is `not is_odd(0)`, which is `not not is_even(0)`, which is `True`. I should've carried it all the way through, thanks for catching that :D

Comment: Btw this technique is called [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) whereby two functions are defined in terms of one another. There's nothing "strange" about it and has all sorts of practical applications. I have written [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20mutual%20recursion) on the topic.

Comment: As @Mulan pointed out, this is not your standard form of recursion. If you are a student, I would strongly suggest you work on understanding the more common form of recursion where a function calls upon itself. If that is clear, mutual recursion will just be a small step for you. It is vital, in my opinion, that learning is done step by step by a small increase in complexity every iteration. Trying to jump directly to the top of the stairs is seldom recommended. Take smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to explain. I ran this in VSCode Debug mode and understood what exactly is happening.
If you don't have VSCode, try doing a dry run on paper with value 1 and then with 2.

I'll try explainig. So we are reducing x by 1 and calling each function alternatively, and line 3 will return `True` when x reaches zero. And each method call basically just negates the other method's output.

So, it's all about how many times the True is flipped to False and then back to True.

In case of even number in `is_even()` method:

True -> False -> True (RUNS ODD NUMBER OF TIMES)

In case of odd number in `is_even()` method:

True -> False -> True -> False (RUNS EVEN NUMBER OF TIMES)

Answer (score 0):

`is_even`: if the argument is 0 returns True otherwise it returns the **same** output as `is_odd(x-1)`

`is_odd`: returns the **opposite** of whatever comes out when it passes it to `is_even`

It's always best to look at the small inputs.

---

###### Sequence A

`is_even(0)`

- in <- 0
- returns True -> True

Out: ***True***

---

###### Sequence B

`is_odd(0)`

- in <- 0
- Sequence A -> True
- odd returns opposite -> False

Out:  ***False***

---

###### Sequence C

`is_even(1)`

- in <- 1
- Sequence B -> False
- even returns the same -> False

Out:  ***False***

---

###### Sequence D

`is_odd(1)`

- in <- 1
- Sequence C -> False
- odd returns opposite -> True

Out: ***True***

---

##### Sequence E

`is_even(2)`

- in <- 2
- Sequence D -> True
- even returns the same -> True

Out: ***True***

---

##### Sequence F

`is_odd(2)`

- in <- 2
- Sequence E -> True
- odd returns the opposite -> False

Out:  ***False***

hopefully that helps...